# How do you organize class source code in Java?

Tags: java

By now my average class contains about 500 lines of code and about 50 methods.
IDE is Eclipse, where I turned “Save Actions” so that methods are sorted in alphabetical order, first public methods, and then private methods.
To find any specific method in the code I use “Quick Outline”.  If needed, “Open Call Hierarchy” shows the sequence of methods as they called one by one.

This approach gives following advantages:

- I can start typing new method without thinking where to place it in the code, because after save it will be placed by Eclipse to appropriate place automatically.
- I always find public methods in the upper part of the code (don’t have to search the whole class for them)

However there are some disadvantages:

When refactoring large method into smaller ones I’m not very satisfied that new private methods are placed in different parts of code and therefore it’s little bit hard to follow the code concept. To avoid that, I name them in some weird way to keep them near each one, for example:  showPageFirst(), showPageSecond() instead of showFirstPage(), showSecondPage().

May be there are some better approaches?

Comment: Checkout http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Java-Software-Series/dp/0321333020 it will help you write software that is easier to maintain and share with others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, naming your methods so that they'll be easier to spot in your IDE is really not good. Their name should reflect what they do, nothing more.

As an answer to your question, probably the best thing to do is to split you class into multiple classes and isolate groups of methods that have something in common in each of such classes. For example , if you have

```
public void largeMethodThatDoesSomething() {
 //do A
 //do B
 //do C
}
```

which then you've refactored such that:

```
public void largeMethodThatDoesSomething() {
 doA();
 doB();
 doC();
}

private void doA() {};
private void doB() {};
private void doC() {};
```

you can make a class called SomethingDoer where you place all these 4 metods and then use an instance of that class in your original class.

Comment: Isn't it not good to increase the number of classes in project? I remember that in the Java Tutorial they warned not to increase the number of classes uncontrolledly because it  may increase start up time? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#innerClasses

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, I've been down thar road as well. There's even a Performance Tips page for Android development (using Java), which plain ole' tells you not only to make few classes but to avoid methods in favour of public fields, avoid inheritance and polymorphic calls because that adds extra nano seconds delay and in a game loop those are critical. However going to extremes with that will result in unwieldy and hard to maintain code. Try coding properlly and cleanly with separate classes as methods as per your programs business needs...

Comment: ... then if necessary, profile your application, see if there's code that generates performance bottle necks, and try to only optimize that portion by making it less esthetic but more performance friendly. Trust me, coding from the ground up with ONLY performance in mind and nothing else will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Organize your code for its audiences.  For example, a class in a library might have these audiences:

1. An API client who wants more detail on how a public method works.
2. A maintainer who wants to find the relevant method to make a small change.
3. A more serious maintainer who wants to do a significant refactoring or add functionality.

For clients perusing the source code, you want to introduce core concepts.  First we have a class doc comment that includes a glossary of important terms and usage examples.  Then we have the code related to one term, then those related to another, then those related to a third.

For maintainers, any pair of methods that are likely to have to change together should be close by.  A public method and its private helper and any constants related to it only should show up together.

Both of these groups of users are aided by grouping class members into logical sections which are separately documented.

For example, a collection class might have several mostly orthogonal concerns that can't easily be broken out into separate classes but which can be broken into separate sections.

1. Mutators
2. Accessors
3. Iteration
4. Serializing and toString
5. Equality, comparability, hashing

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about physically ordering your methods inside the class, if you can't see it just use Ctrl-O and start typing the method name and you will jump straight to it.

Having self-describing method names results in more maintainable code than artificially naming them to keep them in alphabetical order.

Hint: learn your shortcut keys and you will improve your productivity

Answer (score 1):

Organizing the way you described sounds better than 99% of the Java code I have seen so far. However, on the other side, please make sure your classes don't grow too much and methods are not huge.

Classes should usually be less than 1000 lines and methods less than 150.